# What files to package Atlassian Connect Express Confluence Macro

Tags: confluence, atlassian-connect

I am trying to find what files to upload and where for my web confluence plugin.  I know the `atlassian-connect.json` needs to be uploaded to an https:// location.  Do I upload that project root direct in the same location as well as all the folders, or can I skip uploading the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: This is the second question I've seen from you on StackOverflow regarding Confluence Cloud App development.  It seems you're struggling with the foundational concepts.  I'm a Developer Advocate for the Atlassian Ecosystem.  If you would like to discuss this further with a live person please reach out to me at https://community.developer.atlassian.com/u/rwhitbeck/

Comment: Hey Thanks RedWolves, I was able to finally dig up a tutorial on someone using Heroku to upload their production instance.  I had previously gone through most of the tutorials that atlassian has on their main website with no full process on how to release a cloud plugin.  It was a bit different than the `onprem` version where you just send the packaged .jar to atlassian.  Thank you for responding though and I'll reach out to you directly if I run into any other issues!

Comment: Yeah definitely Cloud and Server are different.  While installing on Server you have total control and can upload your .jar file on a Cloud environment we don't want apps to be installed on the hardware (as is typical with Cloud ecosystems).  So you host it and "describe" your app to the product through the descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to host the whole app on a hosting platform that you choose, and yes that includes the atlassian-connect.json file.  Once you upload it and have it running you can install it into your Confluence app using the url to your atlassian-connect.json file.

If you haven't already, you should go through the [Getting Started](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/getting-started/) guide on the docs. This will walk you through setting up an app and getting it running locally and installing a running app into Confluence.